# escape drive name in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

My Batch file test.bat

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c FOR /D %i IN (C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\ssl\*) DO RD /S /Q "%i"
```

When I run above command manually from command prompt, it works well and deletes all contents from C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\ssl.

Now, same command when used in batch file and when I run batch file, it returns :

C:>test.bat

```
C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c FOR /D \ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\ssl\*) DO RD /S /Q "i"

\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\ssl\*) was unexpected at this time.
```

Above output miss out the (C: from the batch file.

Any idea ? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You need to double the percent symbols in a batch file.

Comment: And it does help to read the HELP file for the command you are trying to use. `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.`

Comment: We should also note that you do not have to use `cmd.exe /c` in your batch file nor at the the cmd prompt.  Just use the FOR command directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a different one!

Note how the `%i` is missing in your output when running from the command-line? And a lot of different things as well up to your next `%i` from the command-line line?

When using a for-loop in batch, you have to escape a single percent sign with another one for the loop parameter:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c FOR /D %%i IN (C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\ssl*) DO RD /S /Q "%%i"
```

should be working :)

Comment: @Viral Glad to hear that! Note that you can accept an answer that solved your problem by clicking the grey checkmark next to it. This will not only help to keep the system clean but also reward you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without a for loop?

```dos
Cmd.exe /C RD /S /Q "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\ssl*"
```